# Smartphone camera wired trigger over audio

Tags: audio, camera, android, trigger

I'm trying to build for myself a smartphone camera wired trigger over audio input/output port (a.k.a. 3.5 mm jack used for heaphones/headsets). I'm completely lacking electronic engineering skills (only what learned back in school). So here it goes..

There is such [3.5 mm Headset: Accessory Specification](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec), which I think is the go to for what I'm trying to do..

After trying the headset that I have both Volume - and Volume + perform the same task - take a photo, no matter which button you press. Thus from specification it would be either Function B or Function C - doesn't matter much which.

So the questions that I have are:

1. Can I safely remove buttons (and resistors associated with them) that I don't need in this case from the schematics safely (in this case Function A and Function D buttons, and optionally one of Function B or Function C), leaving with just one button - either Function B or Function C in the schematics?
2. Can I safely not include both speakers in the schematics?
3. Can I safely remove the microphone from the schematics or do I have to replace it with a resistor?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Yes, you can omit them. Look at handsfree headsets. Same exact thing as headphones except only one speaker.

And maybe. The phone may not recognize a remote is connected if the mic is completely missing. You are essentially making what's known as a quick klick (click) button. Simple and done by many, as well as super cheap commercial versions.

Keep in mind the Wired Audio Headset Specification is for **devices** to conform to **Android Specs**. It is required that android devices support the feature, not a requirement that the headset have the feature. Even then, it's just "strongly recommended" that the device support it.